# Selenium Webdriver - Unable to find element after page refresh/redirect

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sap, webui

I am trying to write some UI test cases for an SAP-webUI (web based) application. After login, it shows the dashboard ( Workcenter's ) screen.

Now the problem is, I am able to open the page, enter U/N, Pwd and login through Selenium. After i press the "Login" button the URL changes and the page got redirected/refreshed.

E.g. URL before login : https://a/b/c/d/e/f/g.htm?sap-client=001&sap-sessioncmd=open

E.g. URL after successful Login : https://a/b(bDsdfsdsf1lg==)/c/d/e/f/g.htm

After this im unable to perform any action or press any link in any part of the page. I tried with all the possible attributes ( css, xpath, id ). Webdriver was unable to find any element on the page. It shows the error "No element found" alone.

I am using java with Selenium Web Driver.

Please find the html structure of the webpage below

```
<html><body><div><div><iframe>#document<html><head></head><frameset><frameset><frame>#document<html><head></head><body><form><div><div><table><tbody><tr><td><div><ul><li><a id=abcdef></a></li></ul></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></form></body></html></frame></frameset></frameset></html></iframe></div></div></body></html>
```

Actually i want to click a linkmenu "abcd", which is inside iframe and frame as shown in the below HTML code

`<html><head></head><body><iframe name=a1><html><head></head><frameset><frameset name=fs1><frame name=f1><html><head></head><body><table><tbody><tr><td><ul><li><a id=abcdef>`

I tried the below code as well.

`driver.switchTo().frame("a1");
driver.findElement(By.id("abcd")).click();`

OR

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='abcd']")).click();`

After using the above code, still im getting the error "No such element"

Kindly suggest

Regards,
Siva

Comment: Switch to iframe then switch to the frame contained within that iframe.

Comment: I tried the below code, it shows no such frame exist

driver.switchTo().frame("a1");
driver.switchTo().frame("f1");
driver.findElement(By.id("abcd")).click();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it this way...

> driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='a1']"))); // switching to iframe

followed by

> driver.switchTo().frame("f1"); // switch to frame

and then your desired action...

> driver.findElement(By.id("abcd")).click();

Comment: Hi,
Still im gettitng "No element found" error
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element

Comment: Please find the HTML hierarchy till the link menu


`<html><head></head><body><iframe name=a1><html><head></head><frameset><frameset name=fs1><frame name=f1><html><head></head><body><table><tbody><tr><td><ul><li><a id=abcdef>`

Comment: and at which line u r getting exception?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: no such frame
  (Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9152_7396}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=41.0.2272.101, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]

Comment: In the below command
driver.findElement(By.id("abcd")).click();

Comment: Hi, Im getting no frame found error only in chrome. In IE and firefox it is working fine.
Can you provide me the suitable code to use in chrome
@alecxe

Comment: Hi,
The above code works fine in IE. But not in chrome.
If i execute it in chrome it shows 'No frame found'
Kindly help

Comment: Hi..please provide the html of chrome.

Answer (score 2):

This is *because of the `iframe`*. You need to **switch to it first**:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.id("abcdef")).click();
```

where `0` is a frame index.

Comment: Hi,

After using the above code, still im getting the error "No such element" as below.

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element

Actually i want to click a linkmenu "abcd", which is inside iframe and frame as shown below
<iframe name=a1><frameset><frameset name=fs1><frame name=f1><a id = abcd>

I tried the below code as well.

driver.switchTo().frame("a1");
driver.findElement(By.id("abcd")).click();

OR

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='abcd']")).click();

Kindly suggest

Regards,
Siva

Comment: Hi, Im getting no frame found error only in chrome. In IE and firefox it is working fine. Can you provide me the suitable code to use in chrome @alecxe

Answer (score 1):

See doc on implicit wait [here](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

I guess you should do a implicit wait until your chosen element is available

modify these code to suit your chosen element:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```